# AngularJS - Can I bind an object to an entire form?

Tags: angularjs, forms

You'd think this is already part of Angular but I can't find it.  You can bind form *fields* to variables in $scope using ng-model. But we're constantly binding, like, 100 fields exactly like this:

```
<form>
  <input name="foo" ng-model="object.foo" />
  <input name="foo2" ng-model="object.foo2" />
  <!-- and so on ... -->
</form>
```

Does Angular provide a way to bind a form and have each field bind to it's corresponding object property?  Something like this?

```
<form ng-model="object>
  <input name="foo" />
  <input name="foo2" />
  <!-- and so on ... -->
</form>
```

You'd think something like that should exist, right?  It violates [DRY](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don't_Repeat_Yourself) to individually bind by hand.  It's also inflexible if the model changes.

Comment: Nop, ng-model fits only for input elements.

Comment: Violating DRY is duplicating the form over and over. Not because you need to bind `ng-model` to each input. Although the functionality you've suggested would be quite cool to have..

Answer (score 1):

As fals stated your approach seems messy. 
I assume that you may want to repeat a model and dynamically create a form.

Using ng-form you may dynamically repeat a model bind ng-model on your $scope. 
The pretty awesome part is that you may even have validation!

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="human in people">
               <ng-form name="customform{{$index}}">
            <input type="text" id="email{{$index}}" ng-model="human.email" id="email{{$index}}" required>
            </ng-from>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdk5M/1874/)

Comment: You assume too much, @Theodore.  :-)  I don't want to dynamically create a form.  I want to create a form without having to repeat "ng-model='whatever-the-property-is-named'.  You'd think Angular could infer each object property based on the <input name="property" />.  So ... very cool thought you have! But not what I was asking.  (+1 for the idea and the jsFiddle).